# Reaction to radio button status with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, radio-button

I'm new to JS and to jQuery, I only want to implement a single feature with it at this time. So my question might look naive.

My HTML form has several rows and two columns: left and right. The left column contains all the same radio button selections that the right column does. I would like to make this radio button form to work in such a way that if a particular choice is made in the left column, the same choice must become unavailable (greyed out) in the right column, and vice versa.

[image]

The JS/jQuery script below is supposed to do just that, but how to undo the associated action when a certain radio button is deselected? Is it necessary to get all the form elements in a column and go over each one of them checking if it needs to be un-greyed-out, or is there a simpler method?

```
function toggleRadio() {
      left = $("input[type='radio'][class='left_column']:checked");
      left_val = left.val();
      right = $("input[value=" + left_val + "][class='right_column']");
      left.change(function() {
        right.attr('disabled', true);
      }).change();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say that I fully understand what you want to do. But I hope this example is will work for you.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">

    <div class="form-check">
      <label>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="group1" value="rad1" checked>
        Option 1
      </label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-check">
      <label>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="group1" value="rad2">
        Option 2
      </label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-check">
      <label>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="group1" value="rad3">
        Option 3
      </label>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col">
  
     <div class="form-check">
      <label>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="group2" value="rad1" checked disabled>
        Option 1
      </label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-check">
      <label>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="group2" value="rad2">
        Option 2
      </label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-check">
      <label>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="group2" value="rad3">
        Option 3
      </label>
    </div>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS** (jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
  
        var name  = $(this).prop("name"),
          val   = $(this).val(),
          target = (name === "group1") ? 'group2' : 'group1';
          
    $("input[type='radio']").prop("disabled", false);


    $("input[name='" + target + "'][value='" + val + "']")
        .prop("checked", true)
        .prop("disabled", true);
  
  });


}); //doc ready end
```

**Demo**
https://jsfiddle.net/caneroncel/3vmstpjf/20/

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for, except I had to remove the `.prop("checked", true)` part.

Comment: I changed it to `.prop("checked", false)`. Thanks again.